# C++: SIGSEGV on ToUnicode function (windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, segmentation-fault

First, please forgive my bad english ;)

I want to use the windows function ToUnicode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert a virtual key code into an unicode char with C++.
But everytime I call that function, Windows7 says "MyProcess funktioniert nicht mehr" - I don´t know the english eqiuvalent, perhaps it´s "MyProcess does not work any more"?!  - and I have the choice to debug MyProcess or to Close.

However my gdb debugger shows that I get a SIGSEGV, which tells me there is a data access violation I think.

This is the code I use:

```
BYTE kbd[256];
GetKeyboardState(kbd);
UINT vk = 65;   //vitual key represents 'a'
UINT sc = 30;    //scan code represents 'a'
LPWSTR chars;

ToUnicode(vk,sc,kbd,chars,2,0);
```

I even tried the ToAscii function and i get the same error : SIGSEGV

Can you please help me? =)

Comment: chars is an uninitialized variable, it doesn't point to a buffer.  Kaboom!

Comment: Wow! You almost blew my eardrums!

Comment: oh you`re right...i spent hours =(
but why do i hav to initialize?...

Comment: @brauni: LPWSTR is a pointer, so you have to make it **point** at something. Right now, it's pointing at nothing.

Comment: but is it not possible to let it point to NULL?

Comment: The function assumes that `chars` already has some memory set aside for it and that it's free to write to that memory. The next argument tells the function exactly how much memory is set aside. The function then just fills it in with the requested information (in this case the Unicode characters). What you have is an uninitialized pointer. It doesn't have any memory at all to use. Pointing to NULL (AKA 0) would not work either, because it doesn't own the memory located at 0x0. You actually have to make room for what you need before the function can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToUnicode expects a buffer where it can write the translation result to.

You give it an unitialized pointer pointing somewhere (random) in your memory - this is where the segfault is coming from, ToUnicode tries to write to memory which doesn't belong to your process.

See the following example for correct usage of this function

```
//Just a snippet showing the initialization the buffer part    
const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 2; //Length of the buffer
WCHAR chars[BUFFER_LENGTH];

ToUnicode(vk,sc,kbd,chars,BUFFER_LENGTH,0);
```

Comment: Can you give me an advise for the buffer size? Should I choose 2 or more or less and why?

Comment: Choose whatever you need based on the situation. If you need at most 10 characters, use 10 as your buffer size. Don't forget that the unicode string might not be null-terminated, according to the documentation for `ToUnicode` though.